# Remove Database from Restoring and Single User State

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

Hi I was doing the restoring in new database named XYZ and after restoring my existing database was seems as like below image.

[image]

Can any one say me how Can I delete the old Database and remove the restoring from Live DataBase.
I think the problem was that the .bak File I have restore in Live was same as I have restored the .bak in xyz database.

I just need to remove the Restoring from live database and need all the old database data as safe.

Comment: You should ask this on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Right click > Delete on the old database doesn't work? Note, this would delete the .mdf and .ldf files (not just detach the database)(

Comment: You have not mentioned how have you restored Live DB and how did you make Old database status to Single user mode. If you could answer these questions, then i will be able to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that your database stuck in restoring state. You can use the below statement to solve this problem

```
RESTORE DATABASE DBName WITH RECOVERY
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are lot of databases in this mode, and we want to clean up the master database, select all the databases that are not online.

```
select name, state_desc from sys.databases where state_desc <> 'ONLINE'
```

Copy the names of the databases that are not online, and create a script to delete the databases.

```
 Drop database *dbname1*
 Drop database *dbname2*
```